# Does anyone else engage in reciprocal voting?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, voting

Meaning: I just upvoted a question on Stack Overflow where I provided the accepted answer. My thinking was simple - this person has provided me with points/reputation, so I'm obligated to return the favor.

Does anyone else engage in this type of behavior? Is this behavior bad for Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Wasn't there a suggestion way back that points should be switched off for a week, to see what happens? What happened to that?

Comment: No way! This is not a reputation trading platform.

Answer (score 18):

No. If I did, I'd have to stop answering lousy questions. Or start up-voting lousy questions. Either way, it doesn't sound like much fun.

Not sure why you'd feel obligated - you provided the OP with an *answer*, and that's probably more valuable than whatever you're getting out of an "accept" mark.

Comment: Would +2 this if I could...

Comment: @Squillman. If you downvote, then remove it days later, he'll *seem* to get +2.

Comment: @devin nice, I'll have to file that for future reference.

Answer (score 7):

Stackoverflow works best when you vote based on the quality of the question/answer. Reciprocal voting does not follow this pattern. You are free to vote as you see fit, but I would suggest you not case reciprocal votes.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes.  If it was a good/great question I would have already upvoted it, but if it was just average, I might not except reciprocally.  I would never upvote a crappy question.

I always appreciate having an answer accepted.

Comment: **`except reciprocally`**? Do you mean **`expect reciprocity`**? Sorry, but my inner nit is out in force today.

Comment: @Peter, no I meant that I usually wouldn't vote for an average post except in the reciprocal case that the questioner was asking about.

Comment: Oh. Got it. I completely misunderstood the sentence. Thanks.